# Why isn't my menu (unordered lists) showing up? Menu.css included

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

My goal here is to display the headers and footers inline-table style, which you will see in my menu.css, when this page is ran, the header and footer do no appear at all, but in design view of VS, they appear normally, but not inline.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Home Page</title>
<link type="text/css" href="menu.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body style="background: black; text-align: center">
<header class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="HomePage.aspx">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="Registration.aspx">Become a Member</a></li>
        <li><a>User Information</a>               
            <ul class="subMenu">
                <li><a href="BasicInformation.aspx">Basic Information</a </li>
                <li><a href="DeliveryInformation.aspx">Delivery Infomation</a></li>
            </ul></li>
        <li><a href="Order.aspx">Make Order</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <p style="background-color: #000000">
    <asp:Image ID="bsuImage0" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl="~/Logo/BallStateCardinals02.jpg" class="pic" />
        <asp:Label ID="messageLabel" runat="server" Text="Welcome to Ball State Pizza" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Simplified Arabic" Font-Size="50pt" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
    <asp:Image ID="bsuImage" runat="server" Height="200px" ImageUrl="~/Logo/BallStateCardinals02.jpg" class="pic" />
    </p>
</div>
</form>
<footer class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Contact.aspx">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#top">Back to Top</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my menu.css which sets style for the menu classes in the header and footer.

```
body {}
.menu ul li {display: inline-table; margin-left: 100px;}
.menu ul{padding:0; text-align: center;}
.menu ul li .subMenu{display:none; width:150px;}
.menu ul li:hover > .subMenu {display: block;}
.menu ul li .subMenu li {margin:0; padding-top:5px;}
.menu ul li a{font-size:15px; text-decoration:wavy; color:white;}
.menu {font-size:15px; text-decoration:wavy; color:blue; background-color: red;}
.menu ul li {text-align: center}
```

Comment: Copying and pasting your code exactly as-is, then throwing away the server-side stuff (since that doesn't matter for HTML and CSS), in Chrome shows a black background with two red stripes for nav, the first showing _Home_, _Become a Member_, _User Information_ and _Make Order_ and the second showing _Contact Us_ and _Back to Top_. Hovering over _User Information_ shows two further items. Using these instructions that I've posted, what do you see?

Comment: The menus are completely invisible to me, not sure why @ChrisHaas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried your code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and this is what I got

[image]

Everything seems to be fine here.

Try after clearing the cache, see console for the errors.

Comment: Noob question, but how do I clear VS cache? and what did you change to get it to work?

Comment: I didn't change anything, I just put your code as it was, on jsfiddle and it was working fine. **For Cache:** you have to clear your browser's cache, it stores frequent access pages  in cache and doesn't update them. You will have the clear dialog by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `delete` (on chrome)